# How can I apply a custom function to every value of an xarray.Dataset coordinate?

Tags: python, timestamp, coordinates, python-xarray

I have an xarray.Dataset with a 'time' co-ordinate, with type=datetime64. I want to convert this to a pd.Timestamp, so I can more easily combine and compare other datasets with this one.

Is there a way I can perform the function pd.Timestamp() on each value in the time coordinate, or is there a simpler way I can change the type? Thanks!

Comment: does `ds['time'] = pd.to_timestamp(ds.time.values)` work? see the [`to_timestamp`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_timestamp.html) docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map() function in Python to apply every value in an iterable to a function.

```
def addition(n):
    return n + n
  
numbers = (1, 2, 3, 4)
result = map(addition, numbers)
print(list(result))

Output >> [2, 4, 6, 8]
```